# JQuery Regular Expression for Email using .NET MVC Razor View Engine

Tags: jquery, regex, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have been researching on SO and applying suggestions but none seems to be addressing the issue here. I keep getting

> "regexp.test is not a function"

based on the below. I have tried escaping **`@`** with **`@@`** and still getting the error message. Below is my script:

```
var dialog, form, dialog2,
      emailRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+.[a-z]{0,4}$/,
      FirstName = $("#FirstName"),
      LastName = $("#LastName"),
      Phone = $("#Phone"),
      Email = $("#Email"),
      allFields = $([]).add(FirstName).add(LastName).add(Phone).add(Email),
      tips = $(".validateTips");

function checkRegexp(o, regexp, n) {
    if (!(regexp.test(o.val()))) {
        o.addClass("ui-state-error");
        updateTips(n);
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

dialog = $("#dialog-form").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 550,
    width: 500,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Apply": function () {
            var valid = true;
            allFields.removeClass("ui-state-error");

            valid = valid && checkLength(FirstName, "First Name", 1);
            valid = valid && checkLength(LastName, "Last Name", 1);
            valid = valid && checkLength(Phone, "Phone", 1);
            valid = valid && checkLength(Email, emailRegex, "Email must be valid");

            valid = valid && checkRegexp(Email, "Email", 1);

            if (valid) {
                var url = '/contact/apply';

                var formData = new FormData($("#formApply")[0]);

                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    type: "POST",
                    data: formData,
                    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data["hasApplied"]) {
                            dialog.dialog("close");
                            dialog2.dialog("open");
                        }
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        $(".validateTips").show().addClass("ui-state-error");;
                        updateTips("There was an error with your submission.");
                    }
                });
            }
        },
        Cancel: function () {
            dialog.dialog("close");
        }
    },
    close: function () {
        $("#formApply")[0].reset();
        allFields.removeClass("ui-state-error");
    }
});
```

The emailRegex is not enclosed in quotes and it doesn't work when I escape the **`@`**.

Can anyone see anything that could be causing this function to fail?

Comment: Hilarious!! Totally needed a new set of eyes. Thank you! If you add this as an answer, I can mark it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you accidentally mixed up the parameters in your checks:

```
// Passes Regex
checkLength(Email, emailRegex, "Email must be valid");

// Doesn't Pass Regex
checkRegexp(Email, "Email", 1);
```